# What is course of action required for a low quality question from new user?

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, new-users

I often observed new users posting questions that does not provide enough information to answer the question even after multiple requests in comments to post relevant data. Sometimes the question is of very low quality. But downvotes or flagging will prompt user never to return to SO. Is there a way, low quality posts will get answered but removed after a week so that the site remains clean and new users feel welcome as well?

Comment: "But downvotes or flagging will prompt user never to return to SO" - First of all, that's a guess, not a fact. Second, why care? If someone comes here with complete disregard for the site's rules and customs and asks a crappy, lazy question, downvote and closevote them to oblivion. Either they learn from it or they don't come back, both are positive for SO and way better than answering a crappy question and giving no feedback that it is unwelcome. Feel free to also leave a comment explainig what exactly is wrong with the question; but for the worst posts that's just a waste of time...

Comment: Stack Overflow does **not** exist to answer each and every question. That's **not the goal of the site**. The goal is to collect and curate *great question with great answers*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stack Overflow does **not** exist to answer each and every question. That's **not the goal of the site**. The goal is to collect and curate *great question with great answers*.

If we catered to the low-quality newbie questions *too*, then we'd be flooded by those and would never see the great questions any more. Experts would leave as the site is flooded in crap.

If new users cannot be taught to ask quality questions, but instead stay away, then *that's great*, as such questions go counter to the site's goals.

Comment: "If we catered to the low-quality newbie questions too, then we'd be flooded by those and would never see the great questions any more" - to quote Douglas Adams, `There is another theory which states that this has already happened`...

Comment: @l4mpi: yet downvoting and closing happens. :-)

Comment: Part of the stated goal for SO is: 'With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.'. Saying it's only about great questions with great answers is an elitist idea that keeps raising it's ugly head again and again

Comment: @ClaraOnager: note the 'with your help' part. That also means the OP needs to put in effort. It cannot be our job alone. Not with 7700 new questions each day.

Comment: There's a reward for answering questions for a reason, so if you don't like answering questions, stop doing it - problem solved. My point is that your answer could do with editing to sound less elitist.

Comment: @ClaraOnager: There is also downvoting and closing posts for a reason. There is *nothing elitist* about focusing on the goal of keeping post quality high.

Comment: @Clara There is **no reward** for answering. Only if posts receive upvotes or acceptance, they are _rewarded_, which means **only quality** bring rewards, not the act of answering.